# How to pass id to asp-route-id on the modal button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I have a problem with my code. I have table with 3 columns: category, subcategories and actions. In third column I keep buttons "Edit" and "Delete". Below part of my code:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var category in Model.ToList())
        {

            <tr>
                <td class="hide">@category.Id</td>
                <td>@category.Name</td>
                <td>
                    @if (category.Subcategories != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var subcategory in category.Subcategories.ToList())
                        {
                            <p>@(subcategory.Id + ". " + @subcategory.Name)</p>

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto"
                           asp-controller="administrator"
                           asp-action="CreateSubcategory">
                            Dodaj podkategorię
                        </a>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary"
                       asp-controller="administrator"
                       asp-action="EditCategory"
                       asp-route-id="@category.Id">
                        Edytuj
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" onclick="getId(this.data-id)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="@category.Id">
                        Usuń
                    </button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

When button "Usuń" will be clicked I want show modal window. And this is ok:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Usuwanie kategorii</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć kategorię ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <form method="post">
                <button id="modalDeleteButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                        asp-controller="administrator"
                        asp-action="DeleteCategory">
                    Usuń
                </button>
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally in modal window user have a two choice - close modal window or "Delete" category. In this place I have to know which row was clicked before modal was showing. How to pass @category.Id to my modal window button "Usuń" and set asp-route-id?

Below my JS/JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).find('asp-route-id').val(getId);
});

function getId(clicked_id) {
    return clicked_id;
}
```

Now I have got return url https://localhost:80888/Administrator/DeleteCategory - without "/7" where 7 is Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<tbody>`, the id of this fragment should be sent by @category.Id.

```
<tbody>
    ...
                <button type="button" onclick="getId(@category.Id)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="@category.Id">
                    Usuń
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

In the js function, the call of the `getId` function needs to allocate parameters, so it cannot be called directly to get its value. First, set a global variable. Then, since the browser has compiled `taghelper` into `formaction` when calling modal, this value needs to be reset here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickId;
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).find('asp-route-id').val(getId);
        var btn = $(this).find('#modalDeleteButton');
        console.log(clickId)
        btn.attr('formaction', '/administrator/DeleteCategory/'+clickId);
    });

    function getId(clicked_id) {
        this.clickId = clicked_id;
     }
</script>
```

> Codes of Controller

```
public class administratorController:Controller
{
    public IActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
    {
        return Json(id);
    }
}
```

> Screenshots of Test

[image]

[image]

[image]